# TypeWriter doesn't find inherited properties

Tags: typewriter

Typewriter doesn't seem to pull out inherited properties

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

.tst file

```
namespace ModelNs  {
    $Classes()[
    export class $Name { $Properties()[
        public $name: $Type;]

        public constructor() { }
    }]
}
```

Output

```
namespace ModelNs {

    export class MyClass { 
        public method: string;

        public constructor() { }
    }
}
```

It's missing the Id property.

Yes, I could add the line

```
public id: number;
```

to .tst file as a stop gap, but have more properties to add (than this example).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `$BaseClass` to access properties from inherited classes e.g.

```
namespace ModelNs  {
    $Classes()[
    export class $Name { 

        // Inherited properties
        $BaseClass[$Properties[
        public $name: $Type;]]

        $Properties[
        public $name: $Type;]

        public constructor() { }
    }]
}
```

Comment: note that properties will be dublicated if property is abstract in $BaseClass